# Try and except keywords stopping the program when run in Python

Tags: python, class

My program needs to check if the next area or the previous area in the list is blank. If it is, it will run a piece of code and if not it will run as normal. I tried using the Try and Except keywords, however these only ran 1 section of the code. I tried putting the 2 sections into 2 different objects in a class, however none of them run anymore.

```
#Takes in the equation and puts in int a list
graph_equation = input("Enter graph function: ")
print(*graph_equation)

lst = []


for letter in graph_equation:
    lst.append(letter)



class analyze():
    def __init__(self):
        #Finds number of times x is in the list
        self.x_counter = 0
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(graph_equation)):
            if lst[counter] == 'x':
                self.x_counter += 1
            counter += 1

    def find_a(self):
        #Finds the number multiplied to x
        x_passed = 0
        counter = 0
        while self.x_counter > 0:
            if lst[counter] == 'x':
                self.x_counter -= 1
                x_passed += 1
                try:
                    if lst[counter-1] == '+':
                        print("x", x_passed, "is multiplied by 1")
                    elif lst[counter-1] == '-':
                        print("x", x_passed, "is multiplied by 1")
                    else:
                        print("x", x_passed, "is multiplied by", lst[counter-1])
                except:
                    print("x", x_passed, "is multiplied by 1")
            counter += 1
        print(lst)


    def find_power(self):
        #Finds the power of each x
        x_passed = 0
        counter = 0
        while self.x_counter > 0:
            if lst[counter] == 'x':
                self.x_counter -= 1
                x_passed += 1
                try:
                    if lst[counter+1] == '+':
                        print("x", x_passed, "has the power of 1")
                    elif lst[counter+1] == '-':
                        print("x", x_passed, "has the power of 1")
                    else:
                        print("x", x_passed, "has the power of", lst[counter+1])
                except:
                    print("x", x_passed, "has the power of 1")
            counter += 1





Equation = analyze()
Equation.find_a()
Equation.find_power()
```

Tried putting both sections in a class

Comment: your while statements are `while x_counter > 0`, but you initialise `x_counter = 0`. Your while statements will never start, and doesnt have anything to do with the `try/except` blocks.

Comment: Also, note that try-except is used to handle errors. Mean that if there is any error in the code, it will go to except section, and then the code stop. If you want to handle normal conditions just use if-else

Comment: I fixed x_counter in the new updated code, however the issue hasn't been fixed. It runs Equation.find_a() and then stops

Comment: Exactly, because by the time `find_a` has finished, `self.x_counter` is back to zero again.  You should be using LOCAL variables for those while loops.  And, by the way, you can replace your ENTIRE `__init__` with `self.x_counter = lst.count('x')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just made a different independent x_counter for each section. Solution provided by: Tim Roberts

```
#Takes in the equation and puts in int a list
graph_equation = input("Enter graph function: ")
print(*graph_equation)

lst = []


for letter in graph_equation:
    lst.append(letter)



class analyze():
    def __init__(self):
        #Finds number of times x is in the list
        self.x_counter = 0
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(graph_equation)):
            if lst[counter] == 'x':
                self.x_counter += 1
            counter += 1

    def find_a(self):
        #Finds the number multiplied to x
        x_passed = 0
        counter = 0
        x_counter1 = self.x_counter
        while x_counter1 > 0:
            if lst[counter] == 'x':
                x_counter1 -= 1
                x_passed += 1
                try:
                    if lst[counter-1] == '+':
                        print("x", x_passed, "is multiplied by 1")
                    elif lst[counter-1] == '-':
                        print("x", x_passed, "is multiplied by 1")
                    else:
                        print("x", x_passed, "is multiplied by", lst[counter-1])
                except:
                    print("x", x_passed, "is multiplied by 1")
            counter += 1


    def find_power(self):
        #Finds the power of each x
        x_passed = 0
        counter = 0
        x_counter2 = self.x_counter
        while x_counter2 > 0:
            if lst[counter] == 'x':
                x_counter2 -= 1
                x_passed += 1
                try:
                    if lst[counter+1] == '+':
                        print("x", x_passed, "has the power of 1")
                    elif lst[counter+1] == '-':
                        print("x", x_passed, "has the power of 1")
                    else:
                        print("x", x_passed, "has the power of", lst[counter+1])
                except:
                    print("x", x_passed, "has the power of 1")
            counter += 1





Equation = analyze()
Equation.find_a()
Equation.find_power()

print(lst)
```